# How to properly serve the create-react-app index from the server?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm developing an application with create-react-app and all is going well, except for the fact that I would like to initially serve the `index.html` from the backend, and am running into trouble doing so.

The reason that I want to do this is so that I can inject some user-specific Javascript into the `index.html` page and also run various other queries when the user initially hits the page ([similar to this person](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1588#issuecomment-283305703))

So, instead of connecting to `localhost:3000` to view the app, I would instead connect to `localhost:8080` and have the server serve this `index.html` file. (all other assets (js, css, images) would still be on `localhost:3000`)

One issue with doing this seems to be that the script tags are not included in the `index.html` file by default, and are instead generated by create-react-app. That is, say this is my `index.html` file:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I run `npm start`, and then inspect the source, it will instead be this (due to CRA runtime injections I presume):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script>
</html>
```

As a result, on the server, I'm currently trying something like this:

```
#[get("/")]
fn handle_index() {
    let scripts = r#"<script src="https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
                     <script src="https://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script>
                     <script src="https://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script>"#;

    let index_html = include_str!("../frontend/public/index.html");

    let document = format!(r#"<script type="application/javascript">
                                 window.APP_GLOBALS = { user_id: 5, color: "red" };
                              </script> {}{}"#, data, index_html, scripts);

    return document;
}
```

Because I'm not sure of any other way to inject those script tags. It looks like create-react-app only does it for my `localhost:3000` page, and not the `localhost:8080` page.

This seems to *somewhat* work. That is, the page loads, but there are two issues.

1. Many of the asset URLs are now wrong. They are instead pointing to `localhost:8080` instead of `localhost:3000`, and `%PUBLIC_URL%` URL likewise doesn't work (I suppose this is another process that is no longer occurring)
2. The websocket autoreload dev server no longer works. It works when I navigate to `localhost:3000`, but not `localhost:8080`. When I edit a file and save, the page just turns white with no errors in the console.

I think all of these issues are due to the same cause: `create-react-app` normally preprocesses the `index.html` file in some way (converting `%PUBLIC_URL%`, adding those script tags, handling reload), but it is no longer doing this when the file is instead returned from the server.

What I'm wondering is how I can restore this functionality. Basically, have these script tags and `%PUBLIC_URL%` processes occur without my backend server having to attempt to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `npm start`, you are telling CRA to make a development build using webpack. Webpack does all of the processing you see like injecting scripts and replacing `%PUBLIC_URL%`. You don't want your backend to serve the `index.html` in the `public` folder because that file hasn't been processed by webpack. Instead you need the backend to serve webpack's build output.

The `npm start` configuration is a development build, which is good for development but not production. (Also it doesn't save its output to the file system, so you couldn't even serve it from your backend if you wanted to. See [CRA issue #1070](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1070)). If you run `npm run build`, you get a production build in the `build` folder, which you should serve from your backend (and then you can make whatever injections you need).

The downside of this is that it takes longer to build, it doesn't rebuild automatically when you change your frontend files, and I'm not sure if the errors it gives are as useful as `npm start`. Thus you might want to use `npm start` when developing the frontend and `npm run build` when testing your backend. There are also certain projects like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) that would allow you to make `npm start`'s build output stay in the file system so you can serve it, but I haven't tried any of them.

BTW - be careful with injecting scripts into the html from your backend. Consider something like setting cookies in your backend and reading those cookies in your frontend instead. This is safer, easier to debug, etc.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the original post that this does already work with `npm run build`. The issue is that on every single change I make I have to manually re-run the build and then re-run the server (so it can grab the new files). I also then no longer have auto-reload and errors are impossible to debug since it's all minified. So, not a very good debugging solution. Also, using `npm start` won't work either because then I am not hitting the `/` backend route and receiving the information that I need from the server to run the app.

Comment: Those are good points. What I did when I had this problem is make a modified version of the webpack config files in the react-scripts npm package and add instructions in my readme of how to copy them to the right place in node_modules. This is a pretty bad solution and I think cra-build-watch or [this](https://gist.github.com/jasonblanchard/ae0d2e304a647cd847c0b4493c2353d4) would be better. Either way, find some way to run what is basically `npm start` but with file system output and serve that from your backend (not just `index.html`, the whole folder of bundled js files)

Comment: And seriously consider cookies or an API call instead of plaintext script injection

Comment: Doesn't that solution cause it to build on every change? So it would still not be debuggable since it would be completely minified? Also, the ideal is basically serving `index.html` and the API from the backend and all other assets from the frontend (as this was simulate the structure in production)

Comment: It causes it to create a quick, not-minified development build on change, which is exactly what `npm start` does, just saved to the file system. `npm run build` takes longer and is minified, but this solution would be different.

Comment: The way webpack works is it bundles all your `src` and `public` files into a build folder, which includes `index.html`, minified js files, and other assets. When you load the page in a browser, the browser requests the path `/` from the server and gets `index.html`, which has links to js files and other assets located in the build folder. The browser then requests these assets from the backend as well, and your server serves them. Your backend framework should have some way of serving static assets from a folder, like Express has `express.static`, and you shouldn't have to list each resource.

Comment: Does this need to be ejected to work? I'm getting this error now: `Cannot find module 'react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js'` when using [this](https://gist.github.com/jasonblanchard/ae0d2e304a647cd847c0b4493c2353d4)

Comment: I think that script is outdated. It doesn't seem to work any more with the current react-scripts. It looks like react-scripts now instead has these files: `webpackDevServer.config.js` and `webpack.config.js`. I'm trying to fix it at the moment but not having any luck

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix the script and am now serving all my assets from my backend in debug mode, but there is still the issue where hot reloading doesn't work, because there is no live websocket connection server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205486/discussion-between-noam-bendelac-and-ryan-peschel).